# TFS 2010 - Baseless Merge and How disable automatic resolve conflicts?

Tags: tfs, merge, conflict, resolve

We need to make a baseless merge between two release versions. 
We need a customer that have a release 2.0.1 of system and another with release 5.0.6
A bug was fixed in 2.0.1 and we need to merge in release 5.0.6, but this two releases are not branches.

So I will execute tf merge /bassless release1 release2 /recursive.

But there are a lot of differences between this 2 versions, I need only to create a link (branch relation) between this 2 releases ignoring all conflicts.

I am afraid that this baseless merge operation has been doing a silent resolve conflicts for some files... I don't want this. I want to keep the target files.

Is there another safe way to execute this procedure ? 
Are there someway to disable silent automatic resolve conflicts ?

Thank you

Comment: Automatic resolving of conflicts only happens in TFS 2012 clients.  What makes you think that automatic resolving of conflicts is happening?

Answer (score 0):

the command is as follows:

```
tf merge /recursive /version:Cchangesetnumber~ Ctowhichchangesetnumber /baseless sourcebranch targetbranch
```

Cchangesetnumber~ Ctowhichchangesetnumber – if for instance we were asked to get

a.  changeset # 11367 over into the release candidate branch then our command would have looked like:

```
tf  merge /recursive /version:C11367~C11367 /baseless C:\TFS\Development C:\TFS\Release_Candidate.
```

b.  changeset # 11367 and 11368 over into the release candidate branch then our command would have looked like:

```
tf  merge /recursive /version:C11367~C11368 /baseless C:\TFS\Development C:\TFS\Release_Candidate
```

c.  changeset # 11367 and 11378 over into the release candidate branch then our command would have looked like:

```
 tf  merge /recursive /version:C11367~C11367 /baseless C:\TFS\Development C:\TFS\Release_Candidate
```

and

```
 tf  merge /recursive /version:C11378~C11378 /baseless C:\TFS\Development C:\TFS\Release_Candidate
```

all this runs from "Visual Studio X64 win 64 command prompt"